# Is there a way to ignore escape sequences in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

```
import re
import math
def encode(n, strng):

    for z in range (n):
        temp = []
        spcPos = []


        for i , x in enumerate(strng):
            if x == ' ':
                spcPos.append(i)
        strng = re.sub(' ', '', strng)

        for i in range (len(strng)):
            temp.append(strng[i - n])

        temp2 = []

        ezEnu = 0

        for i in temp:
            if ezEnu in (spcPos):
                temp2.append(' ')
                ezEnu += 1
            temp2.append(i)
            ezEnu += 1

        temp2 = ''.join(temp2)
        temp2 = temp2.split()
        temp = []

        withSpc = []

        withSpc2 = []

        oglen = []

        for i in temp2:
            oglen.append(len(i))
            for x in range (math.ceil(n / len(i))):
                withSpc.append(i)
            withSpc2.append(''.join(withSpc))
            withSpc = []

        newa = []

        for i, x in enumerate(withSpc2):
            for y in range(int(oglen[i])):
                newa.append(x[y - n])

        temp2 = []

        ezEnu = 0

        for i in newa:
            if ezEnu in (spcPos):
                temp2.append(' ')
                ezEnu += 1
            temp2.append(i)
            ezEnu += 1

        strng = ''.join(temp2)

    return(''.join([str(n), ' ', strng]))
```

**How can I take a string, and make it so the escape sequences are treated as regular characters?**

I have this function encode that takes a string and encodes it. The problem is when I receive strings that have a / in or any escape sequence, it ignores them and does not treat it as part of the message to encode.

I have no control over the strings that come into the function, they are predefined.

From what I understand r'' only works on new strings.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what you want exactly you might check whether this is sufficient for your use case.

```
def encode(n, strng):
    return repr(strng)[1:-1]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. this seems to create a double / in the string. This is definitely workable for my issue, yet as my program requires there to be the same amount of characters in the string at all times this still does not work,

I can at-least replace the /'s with an unused character now and change it back at the end, but I'm still wondering if theres other ways of doing this if you can think of any :) Thankyou :))

Comment: Probably you can use `replace()` or `re.sub()` to do what you want.

However there's loads of different interpretations of what exactly you'd like to achieve.

So you had to lay out the __exact__ rules you'd like to apply. 

One probably quite unambiguous way would be, that you 
place the input value into one variable (e.g. `inputvar`) and the expected result into another var (e.g. `expected`)

Then just post in your question the output of:
`print(repr(inputvar), "->", repr('expected'))`

Ideally you give a few examples to be sure we really understand what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I feel like I have a good grasp on this subject now. The first solution you gave me worked well enough, and if I encounter it again I know the options thanks to you ! I appreciate your time thank you :)